# node gyp says build tools are undefined

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I have installed the latest Visual Studio Build tools 2022 using these instructions: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

- Windows 7 Enterprise x64
- node -v v14.15.0
- npm -v 6.14.5
- node-gyp@9.1.0

This is my env:

[image]

This is my **.npmrc** file:

```
msvs_version=2017
msbuild_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

> Following the path to my build tools:
> [image]

Following the MSBuild.exe I run this file and get:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
> [image]

The error message when trying to install a package I get is:

> npm install
> [image]

Now it gets interesting: running gyp configure I don't get the same error:

[image]

I wonder what else can I do? I went trough countless threads and couldn't resolve this issue.
I have a machine with windows 10 on, and did the exact same procedure and it works. But here, the path to the build tools can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot you are using [node-gyp 5.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/5.1.0), not 9.1.0, which is three years old at this point. So it not finding Visual Studio 2022, which was released last year, isn't unexpected.

You need to update your node-gyp version (or node, since node v14 is also old). If you update to a new version of node the installer will ask you if you want to install the build tools as well which is usually a good idea.

If you however want to upgrade your current node-gyp you can follow these steps, assuming node is installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` (taken from the [node-gyp docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/docs/Updating-npm-bundled-node-gyp.md#windows))

```bash
cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script"
npm install node-gyp@latest
```

Comment: ```C:\Users\_\Desktop>npm -g install node-gyp@latest
C:\Users\_\Apps\node\node-gyp -> C:\Users\Auteroid\Apps\node\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.j
+ node-gyp@9.1.0
updated 1 package in 7.308s``` is this fixed ?

Comment: I installed latest node-gyp and the error persists.  "node-gyp -v v5.1.0" why is the gyp version not changing? @npmcli folder does not exist.

Comment: ```C:\Users\_\Desktop>node-gyp -version
node-gyp@9.1.0  C:\Users\_\Apps\node\node_modules\node-gyp
node@14.15.0```

Comment: According to the docs it isn't the global node-gyp that needs updating, it is the one inside npm. Nodejs comes bundled with npm which in turn comes bundled with node-gyp, and that is the one that is used during install. So try following the instructions I copied from the docs (or check the docs I linked).

Comment: thank you I didn't know there was a bundled gyp. I updated it successfully and now trying to fix another issue that came right after. But it seems that it found visual studio now.

Comment: the other issue with msbuild exe was solved by installing net framework 4.7

Comment: I was able to install everything now. Thank you very much.